# How can I see the position of the vertical scroll on an AngularJS form?

Tags: angularjs

I tried this:

```
xx<div>{{ window.scrollY; }}</div>xx
```

But it does not seem to give anything. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: did you mean `$window`?

Comment: $window still does not seem to work :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work that way cos, you need to add $window to your scope.You can do that by adding it in your controller as in example below.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('Ex', function ($window) {
  this.$window = $window;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ex as Ex">
  {{Ex.$window.scrollY}}
</div>
```